# we look forward (for / to) your presence

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is the correct sentence in the below?

We look forward **your presence** with hope and great happiness in the joyous event of our marriage

We look forward **to your presence** with hope and great happiness in the joyous event of our marriage

We look forward **for your presence** with hope and great happiness in the joyous event of our marriage

Comment: Two. And if I could make a constructive criticism: I would cut down on some of the "happy feelings" in the sentence. I feel like it would sound more sincere if it were more concise and to the point.

Comment: If you google *look forward*, you will find many examples of how it is used and the preposition that it requires.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang, Shall i cut "hope and" from the word

Comment: What's wrong with just, "We look forward to your presence at the joyous occasion of our marriage"? I left you one adjective :D.

Comment: Yes.. this is simple and neat. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

"We look forward to your presence with hope and great happiness in the joyous event of our marriage" is definitely more grammatically-correct.